# how to pop up an AlertDialog in Android Framework

Tags: android

I want pop up an AlertDialog somewhere in Android Framework, the problem is that a ui context is needed, while there is no such a ui context in framework most parts.

after some research, I found an example in AutofillManagerService.java:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/autofill/java/com/android/server/autofill/AutofillManagerService.java;l=199?q=AutofillManage&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject

```java
mUi = new AutoFillUI(ActivityThread.currentActivityThread().getSystemUiContext());
```

here the ui context (`ActivityThread.currentActivityThread().getSystemUiContext()`) will be passed to `SaveUi` to create a dialog:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/autofill/java/com/android/server/autofill/ui/SaveUi.java;l=340;bpv=0;bpt=1

```java
        mDialog = new Dialog(context, mThemeId);
        mDialog.setContentView(view);

        // Dialog can be dismissed when touched outside, but the negative listener should not be
        // notified (hence the null argument).
        mDialog.setOnDismissListener((d) -> mListener.onCancel(null));

        final Window window = mDialog.getWindow();
        window.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        window.setDimAmount(0.6f);
        window.addPrivateFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SYSTEM_FLAG_SHOW_FOR_ALL_USERS);
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER);
        window.setCloseOnTouchOutside(true);
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.accessibilityTitle = context.getString(R.string.autofill_save_accessibility_title);
        params.windowAnimations = R.style.AutofillSaveAnimation;

        show();
```

Howerver, It crashed when I tried to do the same thing, my code is something like:

```java
new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityThread.currentActivityThread().getSystemUiContext())
                    .setTitle("some title")
                    .setMessage("some message")
                    .setPositiveButton("yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("no", (dialog, which) -> {
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Try to call show dialog from places where you can get the activity context. Inject this context as a parameter. Don't forget to check the activity `isFinishing` or not.

Comment: Is there any way to use `ActivityThread.currentActivityThread().getSystemUiContext()` to achieve this goal, instead of introducing an activity context.

Comment: No, this `ActivityThread ` class is hidden from core framework. So, you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and testing, I found the solution finally.

**In Android framework**, we can use `ActivityThread.currentActivityThread().getSystemUiContext()` to create an AlertDialog definitely, even `ActivityThread.currentActivityThread().getSystemContext()` also works, the key is:

```java
window.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY)
```

settings the window type of the dialog is necessary here.

see the example code:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/autofill/java/com/android/server/autofill/ui/SaveUi.java;l=348

I've tested it in both cases (`getSystemUiContext()` and `getSystemContext()`) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to get context in android. In activity, you could get context through **this** keyword, or in fragment, it's maybe **requireContext()**, or simple is **applicationContext**. Did u try this?